# Where is the shub command?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm rather new to the whole scraping idea.  I decided to give scrapy a try and saw the rather simplified directions on https://scrapy.org/.  I can't find anywhere that 'shub' command is defined or described.  I've installed scrapinghub and hubstorage but neither of those seem to include that shub command.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shub` is a separate command that can be installed with `pip` with:

```
pip install shub
```

Comment: great idea, I am creating a [PR](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy.org/pull/91) for this request